# Trying to remove top row from excel spreadsheet using Python

Tags: python, excel

this is my first question here so if I don't follow perfect etiquette please forgive me. I have been searching for an answer for about 6 hours so I figured it was time to ask. I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to automate data entry with Selenium. I'm doing well, but stuck at the part where I pull data from Excel. The data pulling isn't the problem, but telling my excel to delete the top row, or move onto the next, is. Here is a sample of my script:

```
    import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import numpy as np

xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\Steph_000\\Desktop\\students2.xlsx')
xl

wr = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\Steph_000\\Desktop\\students2.xlsx')

xl.sheet_names

['Sheet1']

df = xl.parse('Sheet1') #This reads the sheet into a dataframe
df

cp = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Steph_000\\Desktop\\students2.xlsx')

IDNum = cp[:1] #This pulls the first row as a variable

print(IDNum) #This is where it prints to the search bar to look the student up

chart = cp[1:] #This pulls everything but the first row as a variable

print(chart)

df.to_excel(wr, 'Sheet1')
wr.save() #This is supposed to overwrite it, but just saves it as blank
```

No matter what I do, I can't get it to move up the rows, or anything like that. I'm really struggling and very frustrated. I'll use a different Python wrapper than Pandas if I have to, but I've already tried openpyxl, xlrd, and xlwr to no avail! Pulling my hair out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at example below:

- missing engine='xlsxwriter'
- missing sheet_name='Sheet1

Look at this:

```
            import pandas as pd
            #Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
            df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

            # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

            # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

            # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
            writer.save()
```

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: But that doesn't really help me, because I'm importing a data set not creating one from scratch. I'm trying to overwrite the excel file I imported with the new data (either moving every row but the first one up, to overwrite it, or deleting the first row), so that it can be loaded again after the rest of the script runs, so I can loop it.

Unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Do it in steps.. Take the code above add it to your script and check if it works. Then move in steps to your solution.

Comment: I think I've discovered an easier way to do this, and almost have it working (I plan to ask another question about the syntax, because I can't seem to get it right), but I'm still going to give you the right answer because you did help me out and I know that's a pretty big deal here! Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to but it won't let me til I have high enough reputation :( I will come back and do that for you when I do though!